# Adding phone icon to status bar(Where to remove status bar?)

Tags: android, icons, android-notifications, statusbar

I just want to add phone icon to status bar like in the picture.
Nothing more, just this small icon should be shown in the status bar.

How Can I do this?
Can I get this icon anyway by calling some methods? or should I draw this icon with any tool? Then How to add this icon?

[image]

**EDIT:**
I finally show a notification by using this code:

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_phone_white_36dp)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Hello World!");
// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);


        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(SecondActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(2, mBuilder.build());
```

But I am using two activity in my application. Removing is problem now. I want to remove this notification when user exit the program so where to cancel notification?

```
mNotificationManager.cancel(2);
```

I tried in onDestroy: It is not working, it is not being removed when user exit the program.

```
  @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();  // Always call the superclass method first

        mNotificationManager.cancel(2);
    }
```

I tried in onStop: It is working but when user pass another application, this notification is removed. I do not want like this.

```
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();  // Always call the superclass method first

        mNotificationManager.cancel(2);
    }
```

Finally where to cancel?

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html. The icon is a notification icon.

Comment: What do you mean by exit the program?

Comment: When user exit in second activity, user press home button and terminate app by sliding left

Answer (score 0):

This is a **notification icon**, which is displayed when notification is received. It is attached with the notification *at the time of creating notification*. You can add any type of icon while sending notification. In your status bar, notification has `phone` icon attached with it, which is being displayed. You can find more info about notifications [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can download  the icon from here  https://material.io/icons/#ic_phone

Then to add it on your app you have to create a notification https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Ok, But how to add this icon to status bar?